# How do I programmatically change the page in a Word Document?

Tags: python-3.x, win32com

I am trying to open a Word document and automatically set the current page to the last one. It is called from a GUI application so that when a user clicks, Word opens with a specific document and page.

The current code is below:

```
import win32com.client
word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
word.Visible = True
word.DisplayAlerts = False
doc = word.Documents.Open(filename)
constants = win32com.client.constants
doc.GoTo(constants.wdGoToPage,constants.wdGoToLast)
# The page did not move :(
```

The current page is not moving. According to the [GoTo reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.goto) the syntax should be correct.
Am I missing anything in my code? Or is it just some quirk from win32com/Word/Windows?
If (from what I read from the comments) this method is just meant to move the selection, is there any way to actually scroll the page so that the user gets the document opened on the last page? (and generalizing, on any arbitrary page)

Comment: What is `doc` in this code?

Comment: Reading the documentation you've linked, I don't get the impression that this method is supposed to visibly move or scroll the page. As far as I understand (having never used this), it moves the *selection* of an item in the document model. In your example, the last page in the document would somehow be selected.

Comment: @mkrieger1 my bad, I did not write a correct code. It is now corrected. I also updated the question. Thanks for the clarification!